# System date in Julian Date form?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datetime

I know this question has been asked quite a few times in different ways but I'm not seeing a way to do it so that it gives a current day conversion, all the examples I've seen use past dates but in my case I want to use TODAY's date with a system variable. Now I found code from Microsoft that shows how to do it but two problems with it: 1. It's for a specific date entered into a textbox and doesn't use the system date and 2. It doesn't account for leap years(like this year). Here is the link for that : https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/116281

I tried manipulating the code to pull from the system date but it just keeps giving me errors. I literally just started using VB a few days ago so I'm very very new to this stuff so please forgive me for my limited knowledge. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Btw the format I'm trying to get it in is YYDDD so today would be 16075. I can get the 16 using 
`JulianYear = DateTime.Now.ToString("yy")`
but I can't figure out the day using in built functions and keeping in mind the leap year. So once again any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. If you want help with your code the best way to get it is actually post the code you tried, explain what went wrong, and what it should be doing. Most users wont help someone who has shown no effort at solving their own problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Julian calendar leap year count was different (wrong), so the day count for Mar 15 would be 62.  (Meaning the cumulative Julian error is some 13 days).  What you appear to want is the Gregorian date in Julian format.

The article you cite is for Access 97, and NET has what you want ready to use in the `DateTime` type:

```
Dim dt = DateTime.Now
Dim jDate = String.Format("{0}{1}", dt.ToString("yy"), dt.DayOfYear.ToString("000"))
```

Result:

> "16075"

NET does include the actual Julian calendar:

```
Dim cal = New Globalization.JulianCalendar
Dim jDay = cal.GetDayOfYear(dt)         ' == 62
```

Comment: _This comment is not about the code._ I believe the code you propose is correct, but I disagree with the suggestion that the Julian Calendar had no leap years. In the Julian Calendar, every 4th year was a leap year, so it had more leap years (100 out of every 400) than the Gregorian Calendar (97 out of every 400).

Comment: @Blackwood That didnt seem correct as I typed it, but I was focusing on what the OP really wanted...thanks.

Comment: So if someone asked you for a Julian Date, what is the correct answer? It looks like there are different variations of it, but I often ran into the "245####.5" version a lot. I also saw people using what I had requested, which worked the way I wanted to btw so thanks for that!

Comment: It depends on the context.  There is an astronomical version which often uses the `245...` form.  That would be: `dt.ToOADate + 2415018.5`.

Comment: Ah I see. Well thanks for providing some insight on this Plutonix!!